# Torque-direction of rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

> Taking moment about $A$, the mass of 2.0g and 0.50g is rotated in the clockwise direction is because they are both directed in downwards position? while $R2$ is acted in upward direction, so it is rotated in counter clockwise direction?
>
> Taking moment about $G$, why $R1$ is rotated in the clockwise direction? while 2.0g and R2 is rotated in anticlockwise direction?
>
> How to determine the direction of rotation?

first part of image here:
[http://imgur.com/ZNdGrCN](https://imgur.com/ZNdGrCN)

second part of image here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0j1e.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Note that this site has [MathJax enabled](//physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation), which means you can use Latex-like syntax to add in equations for readability. You can use this to add the necessary equations from your images, rather than forcing users to click links (which can be bad in the event they rot).

Answer (score 1):

Allowing the bar to pivot about point G, you will see that R1 (if it was the only force) would rotate the bar clockwise and R2 (by itself) would rotate the bar counterclockwise.

The direction of rotation is determine by the direction of the force (up or down) and where it acts in relation to the pivot (right or left).

Comment: why Allowing the bar to pivot about point G, you will see that R1 (if it was the only force) would rotate the bar clockwise and R2 (by itself) would rotate the bar counterclockwise.???

Comment: can you explain on that ?

Comment: It's in the question: `Taking moment about G`. The solution is the *Alternative Method*. Note that they made a mistake (2.0kg)(2.0); it should be (2.0kg)(0.2).

Comment: it's not stated whether the $R1$ and $R2$ , $2.0g$ and other masses are rotated in clockwise or anticlockwise direction . How do we determine the direction of rotation ?

Comment: The bar **must** pivot about G when we say `Taking moment about G`. If the force is up and to the left of G, then the bar will rotate clockwise. If the force is up and to the right of G, then the bar will rotate counterclockwise.

Comment: why The bar must pivot about G when we say Taking moment about G. If the force is up and to the left of G, then the bar will rotate clockwise. If the force is up and to the right of G, then the bar will rotate counterclockwise??

Comment: do you mean use LEFT HAND THUMB rule for the forces on the left side of G ? using RIGHT HAND THUMB rule for the forces on the right side of G ?

Comment: `why The bar must pivot about G when we say Taking moment about G.` Read the book! This is standard practice for determining the forces necessary to balance the bar. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQ1vQDLuD54

Comment: do you mean use LEFT HAND THUMB rule for the forces on the left side of G ? using RIGHT HAND THUMB rule for the forces on the right side of G ? –

Comment: I don't know what those rules state, so I can't answer that.